# Unable to set Docker container hostname via Marathon Json file

Tags: json, curl, docker, mesos, marathon

I am trying to set hostname for a container as a part of SQL container testing.
I am using JSON to be POST'ed to Marathon via curl and bring up container through Marathon. However hostname configuration I am using in json doe not seem to be working. Looks something silly I might be missing though.
 Below is json to set hostname.

```
"container":{
  "type":"DOCKER",
  "docker":{
     "image":"10.100.33.1:9000/mon/test-ip-sql-ndb-v2",
     "network":"BRIDGE",
     "privileged":true,
     "parametsr":[
     {
            "key": "hostname",
            "value": "ndb1testip.marathon.mesos"
     }
     ]
  }
```

Can somebody point what am I doing wrong here? I know U can set hostname using.

```
docker run -h <HOSTNAME>
```

But that is not the way I am trying to do.

Comment: could it be as simple as spelling parameters right?

Comment: Indeed it is !! thanks, an extra pair of eye always helps :)